# How to add a CSS class to a dataview element onItemTap event in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, dataview

I have created the dataview list by loading the data from an array in a JSON store using for loop. Due to that, CSS is applied to the entire dataview instead of a single element.

```
{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        store: 'AnswerStore',
        flex:8,
        height: 600,
        width: '100%',
        style: 'background-color:gray; padding: 10px;',
        itemTpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl for="questionAnswers">',
                '<div>{answer}</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>'
        ],
        onItemTap: function (container, target, index, e) {
            var me = this;
            this.setStyle('color:red');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your onItemTap, the new style should be applied to the `target` object (which is the item that's been tapped). Also -*and very important*- the params for onItemTap need to be re-ordered as `function(container, index, target, e)`.

Here's the whole `onItemTap` function:

```
onItemTap: function(container, index, target) {
    target.setStyle({color: 'red'});
}
```

I've got a working fiddle if you want to see it in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8g1

Answer (score 0):

To get this output, create css class and give it to list as pressedCls config.
if you want to overwrite selected style then give it to list as selectedCls config.